# How to deploy a React app to GCP as the front, with a python server as backend?

Tags: reactjs, hosting

I have a `flask` based server running on `GAE` doing some complicated calculations. It exposes a RESTful API.

Now I'm planning to build a nice front for it with `React`. All it will do is showing a fancy form and sending requests to the API with parameters, and receiving calculation results from the flask server, and showing some nice-looking charts. And due to the long time the calculation requires, I'm considering adding WebSocket to it too.

A `node.js` server seems too redundant for this purpose.

How should I host this kind of simple `React` apps?

Is it possible to simply upload the built HTML and JS to a bucket and host it as a static site? If it's possible, some detailed instructions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you go through the below URL to create your react app.
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html Once you create the react-app it will automatically include react-scripts package in your package.json file. It would have automatically included the **"build": "react-scripts build"** in the scripts section. Now in the command prompt if you just run "npm run build" it will create all files in the ./build folder. Copy all the files from build folder to bucket. You must setup index.html as index using gsutil, else it will not work. Additionally if you are invoking any api's set up CORS policy on the bucket as well using the gsutil.